# Date range Parameters in SSRS. Passing same date value to @StartDate and @EndDate is not returning any data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

SSRS Report having Data Range Parameters StartDate and EndDate pointing to DateTime column which is in format 2020-07-05 08:00:00.287

When I select Same Date say 10/05/2020 in StartDate and EndDate expecting record for that single daye but it's not returning/displaying any data. where as I check and see there's data available in the table.

Current Query:
Select * from Table1
Where [DateTime]>=@StartDate AND [DateTime]<=EndDate

Also tried BETWEEN and (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DateTime,101), didn't work.

I want to use StartDate and EndDate as date range parameters and if I select same date(Single date) for both the Parameters it should return data from that Date.
Appreciate any leads on resolving this issue.

Comment: Sample data? What date range are you using and what date are you expecting to show up? The query would also be helpful.

Reading your comments again I think I see what you mean. Start and End is 10/5 and you expect to see 10/5? If your data isn't too large, I'd simply try a `CAST` function. So an example would be ...`WHERE CAST(DateTime as DATE) BETWEEN @Start and @End`

Comment: To explain why this happens, the date is implicitly converted to datetime. So it filters on all datetimes between 2020-05-10 00:00:00 and 2020-05-10 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the DATEADD Function to Increment by 1 Day and Then Compare**

In this scenario where the underlying data in the transactional date column is a DATETIME value, I would just increment the parameter by 1 and create a less than condition as follows:

```
    DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE
    DECLARE @EndDate AS DATE
    
    SET @StartDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    SET @EndDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    ;
    
 SELECT
    *
FROM
    favorite_table
WHERE
        1 = 1
    AND transactional_dt >= @StartDate
    AND transactional_dt  < DATEADD(d,1,@EndDate );
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. It worked. Wondering why  [DateTime] BETWEEN '10/05/2020' and '10/05/2020'

[DateTime]>='10/05/2020' AND [DateTime]<='10/05/2020'   aren't working.

Comment: Since the DATETIME column has values greater than '10/05/2020' (e.g. 1 AM, 2 AM), the condition would not return those records. Some people CAST the DATETIME column as a DATE and that should then work as you expect it (though performance could take a hit).